# Perl Device::SerialPort will not display incoming data with printf (but works with print)

Tags: c, perl, arduino, serial-communication

I'm writing a short problem to talk to an Arduino over a USB serial port.
I have a little test program on the Arduino sending data and everything 
works if I display the data with `print`, but not if I use `printf` (this is in Perl).

The code that doesn't work is below with the `print` statement commented out.  This code will print <> over and over. While if I use the `print` 
instead of the `printf` it will print the incoming data.

```
use Device::SerialPort;

$ob = Device::SerialPort->new("/dev/ttyACM0") or die "new failed\n" ;
$ob->baudrate(115200) or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->parity('none') or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->databits(8) or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->stopbits(1) or die "parm set failed";
$ob->handshake('none') or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->write_settings or die "no settings\n";
while(1){
    ($count, $line) = $ob->read(255);
#   print  $line;
    printf("<%s>\n", $line);
}
```

Comment: Your `printf` statement is fine and that isn't what is happening. Change your code to `print "$count - $line\n";`  `printf "<%s>\n", $line;` and I'm sure you will see that both statements are printing the same value

Comment: You were right.  Nothing is wrong with the printf.  The problem was output buffering.  If the read returns with zero chars then $line="".  With  "print" the empty string it is silently added to the output buffer.  If I use "printf" with the \n  the empty line is printed hence the empty <> brackets.  My new code will test the char count returned from the read before trying to print.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was not the code but the terminals (stdout) buffered output.

The read was returning with zero characters so the $line was an empty string that is silently added to the output line buffer.  Eventually the 
serial data would receive the end of line (\n) and cause the buffer to print displaying the received serial data.

With the formated printf the \n caused the output buffer to print every time the read returned.  And, this displayed and endless stream of empty 
brackets.  This confused the poor terminal operator.

Problem solved.... test the character count returned from the read before trying to printf it.

```
use Device::SerialPort;
$ob = Device::SerialPort->new("/dev/ttyACM0") or die "new failed\n" ;
$ob->baudrate(115200) or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->parity('none') or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->databits(8) or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->stopbits(1) or die "parm set failed";
$ob->handshake('none') or die "parm set failed" ;
$ob->write_settings or die "no settings\n";
while(1){
  ($count, $line) = $ob->read(255);
  if($count >0) {
    printf "<%s>\n", $line;
  }
}
```